# checkpatch.pl flags an error for octal permissions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, coding-style, linux-device-driver

I am trying to resolve some coding style issues in a device driver. When I run checkpatch.pl script to run it, it flags the following error.

**ERROR: Use 4 digit octal (0777) not decimal permissions**

I changed the permissions from S_IWUSR to 0200, but the error still persists.

Comment: Please show us the actual code, that checkpatch.pl barks at.

Answer (score 0):

Use decimal 777. You used octal 0222.

Comment: Did you try chmod 777?

Comment: No. I am trying to fix a driver coding style issue.